# Stream audio from Surface RT to Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: streaming, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

I would like to play music on my Surface RT, but have the audio streamed to and actually played on my Win8.1 PC (it has better speakers than the surface, naturally). With Surface Pro I could have done this with VLC, but alas there is no metro VLC.